# Receiving Err Msg: There is already an open DataReader associated with this Command which must be closed first

Tags: visual-studio, winforms, ms-access, vba

```
        con.ConnectionString = "Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source=C:\Users\Name\Desktop\AccessFile.accdb;"
        con.Open()
        Dim strQ As String = "select * from Table1 where Ticket_No = '" & Text_TicketNo.Text.ToString & "';".ToString
        Dim cmdQ As OleDbCommand = New OleDbCommand(strQ, con)
        Dim QReader As OleDbDataReader
        Dim it As String
        QReader = cmdQ.ExecuteReader
        If QReader.HasRows Then
            While QReader.Read
                it = QReader.Item("user_name")
                MsgBox(it)
            End While
        End If
        cmdQ.ExecuteNonQuery()
        con.Close()
```

Receiving the following error above. Not sure where this connection closure needs to take place. Thanks in advance for the help. Tried to look for this online but couldn't find any help for this issue. Tried using my eyes but i think i just need another person to look at my code and tell me where the problem is. Thanks.

The error is occuring on the following line. `cmdQ.ExecuteNonQuery()`

Comment: Why do you have `cmdQ.ExecuteNonQuery()` there? Did you mean to dispose it instead? Also, the *location* of that exception is likely very useful to know.

Comment: Well wasn't that silly of me. The issue was i had that cmdQ command thinking i was deleting, updating, or inserting a record. Thanks.

Comment: Also, you should always post where the exception occurs in future questions.

Comment: Edited the question for future visitors. There will be many who will make this silly mistake. Thank you once again

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is the extra call here:

```
cmdQ.ExecuteNonQuery()
```

You never need this unless you're issuing a `UPDATE`, `DELETE`, `INSERT`, or any other of the statements that modify stuff. The `SELECT` query statement is only used with `ExecuteReader`.

So remove that line and the exception should go away.